# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer. How do I fix the problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have my own dataset consisting of images of size 100x100 instead of the usual 28x28 (in MNIST). I'm trying to run the code for the DCGAN from the homepage of tensorflow on my dataset, but I fail.

I know that the problem is related to the dimensions, would appreciate if someone could perhaps explain what is missing. I've read that the output of the generator has to match the input of the discriminator, but I have no clue on how to do that. Would appreciate any help, if someone could perhaps explain what I have to adjust?

This is the code for the discrimnator:

```
def make_discriminator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',input_shape=[100, 100, 1]))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))

    return model
```

Here is the code for the generator

```
def make_generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(25*25*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Reshape((25, 25, 256)))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 25, 25, 256) # Note: None is the batch size

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 25, 25, 128)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 50, 50, 64)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 100, 100, 1)

    return model
```

The error I recieve is "ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4 but received input with shape [100, 100]".

Comment: Can you share us the full code or at least the code that yield that error?

Comment: @ĐinhAnhVũ Yes. Where should I put it?

Comment: In your question, of course or a link to it

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this line

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',input_shape=[100, 100, 1]))
```

Input channel for RGB channels value should be 3 instead of 1.

Replace input_shape with

```
input_shape=[100, 100, 3]
```